# No video output after resuming from post screensaver

Tags: video, screensaver, resume

After the OS turns off the output due to idling. Upon pressing keys or jiggling the mouse I can no longer get video output and I have to hold the power button to restart and then the output returns. Tried plugging and unplugging still no dice.

This is a new install. Previously, I was on Manjaro which had its own problems.

Update: It appears there are visual glitches with video and images displaying on webpages. Also have mouse pointer lag. (not input but it looks like is lags as its moves across the screen).

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS
- Linux Kernel: .8.0-50-generic
- Video : Nvidia GeForce 1060 HDMI output
- Driver: X Server Nouveau

[image: Driver Info Image]

Comment: X11 or Wayland? What desktop?

Comment: Does switching to a text console with Ctrl-Alt-F2 and back with Ctrl-Alt-F7 still work?

Comment: @HuHa Cinnamon  desktop. Im a bit a noob at Liunux, what is X11 and Wayland?

Comment: It's two different windowing systems; X11 being the traditional one and Wayland the newer one. But with Cinnamon you probably have X11.

Comment: So, did that change recently after a regular software update? Did you update your graphics drivers? Are you using NVidia binary drivers (which version?) or the Open Source Noveau driver? Please edit your question with that information.

Comment: @HuHa Added the info in the OG post. It is the Noveau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nouveau driver is a heroic effort by volunteers reverse engineering the NVidia hardware, but it tends to have its quirks. Even if you don't care much about gaming performance, it can also have problems with resume after suspend-to-RAM. With NVidia graphics cards, IMHO the latest NVidia proprietary driver is the best option.

I have been using the NVidia binary drivers with my GeForce 1050 Ti for several years now, and they always worked great.

From the selection on your screenshot, I recommend to use the topmost; in general, the hightest number. But make sure to not use any of them ending with -server: They reserve a large part of your graphics card for CUDA calculations.

Comment: It appears to have been fixed! Thanks!

Comment: OK, glad to hear that. Now if you mark the answer as the one that helped you, it might help others as well.